# JSON parser app freezes on running

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am trying to create an app that parses data from a `JSON` parser and populates the `recyclerview` items with the data fetch from the `JSON` but whenever I run it it just freezes at loading and shows no error except adapter not attached skipping layout. I am stuck at a dead end as I am not able to get any further. How can I fix this what is the problem with the code .

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
    ImageView image;
    TextView personName;
    TextView personProf;
    RecyclerView rv;
    private List<Person> personList;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    ImageView images;
    RecyclerViewHeader header;
    ImageView iv;

    public String strurl;
    URL url;
    URI uri;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        personName= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        personProf=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        images= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

        collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Capsule");
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        //setPalette();
        strurl =  "http://www.humanfox.com/capsule/assets/img/jawed_headshot.jpg";

        Typeface face2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        Typeface face4= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load("http://d152j5tfobgaot.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Javed-Habib_11.jpg")
                .into(image);
        //header = (RecyclerViewHeader) findViewById(R.id.header);
        //header.attachTo(rv,true);

        rv =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

       personList= new ArrayList<>();
       getData();
    }
    private void getData(){
        //Showing a progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading Data", "Please wait...",false,false);

        //Creating a json array request
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(COnfig.DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Dismissing progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();

                        //calling method to parse json array
                        parseData(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            Person per = new Person();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                per.setImageUrl(json.getString(COnfig.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
                per.setName(json.getString(COnfig.TAG_NAME));
                per.setPassion(json.getString(COnfig.TAG_PROFESSION));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            personList.add(per);
        }
        adapter = new RVAdapter(personList, this);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    }


}
```

**Recycler view Adapter**

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

        private ImageLoader imageLoader;
        Context context;
        private List<Person> persons;

        RVAdapter(List<Person> persons,Context context){
            this.persons = persons;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,viewGroup,false);
            PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
            return pvh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
            imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
            imageLoader.get(persons.get(i).getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(personViewHolder.personPhoto, R.drawable.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
            personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).getName());
            personViewHolder.personProf.setText(persons.get(i).getPassion());


        }

        @Override
        public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }




        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return persons.size();
           }

        public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
            CardView cv;
            TextView personName;
            TextView personProf;
            ImageView personPhoto;
            Context context;

             PersonViewHolder(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                context = itemView.getContext();
                itemView.setClickable(true);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

                cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
                personName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                personProf = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                personPhoto=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Intent intent;
                int position =getAdapterPosition();
                switch(position){
                    case 0:
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context,caps1.class));

                }
            }
        }


    }
```

**Custom Volley Request**

```
public class CustomVolleyRequest {
    private static CustomVolleyRequest customVolleyRequest;
    private static Context context;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private CustomVolleyRequest(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context) {
        if (customVolleyRequest == null) {
            customVolleyRequest = new CustomVolleyRequest(context);
        }
        return customVolleyRequest;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            requestQueue.start();
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }
}
```

Comment: define "freezes at loading" ... *shows no error except ...* ... no kidding? guess why .... `public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {}`

Comment: Some tips: use GSON for serializing/deserializing (it's a real killer tool, it will make your life easier) and use debugger to go step by step and see where actually your app freezes.

Comment: PLEASE, show the stack trace!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have implemented send request and parse json on background thread not in Main thread. Otherwise, it will freeze because of your main thread can do one task and should do UI update not all tasks together.